# VisualStudio, C# .NET FrameworkでMySQL Connector/Netを用いてデータベースに接続する方法

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, .net

初めてVisualStudio, C# .NET Frameworkを使用します。
VisualStudio, C# .NET Frameworkで、
MySQL Connector/Netを用いてデータベースに接続し、テーブル内のデータを表示させてたいと考えています。
他の方のやり方を参考にやってみているのですが、
以下の方法では
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
部分にエラーだ出てしまい困っております。
アドバイス頂けると幸いです。
※練習用のため、vegrantを用いて仮想のローカールサーバーです。

ここまで行ったこと：
基本的に以下のサイトをトレースしました。
http://web.sfc.wide.ad.jp/~tinaba/tutorials/mysql-net/
MySQL Connector/NetはPCに落としただけで
セットアップなどはとくになにも行っておりません。
（他にセットアップが必要な場合は教えて頂けると幸いです。）
VSでFormプロジェクトを作成しMySQL.Dataを参照から追加し、
ボタンの動作を以下で定義しました。

コード:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //サーバー接続
            string connstr = "userid=***; password=***; database=signup_test; Host192.****";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
            conn.Open();

            // データを格納するテーブル作成
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            // SQL文と接続情報を指定し、データアダプタを作成
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from test1", conn);

            // データ取得
            da.Fill(dt);

            // データ表示
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            // 接続の解除
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Error：
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);部分に注釈で

> System.ArgumentException: '初期化文字列の形式が使用に適合しません。index 53 で始まっています。'

Form:
[image: Form画面]

Comment: 接続文字列(あなたのコードなら`connstr`)に形式的な誤りがあるために実行時に例外が発生している状態です。「index 53 で始まっています。」とあるので、接続文字列の53文字目あたりをよく調べてみてください。参考にされたサイトは誤植の訂正には熱心ではないようですが、同じコードの掲載されている画面写真をよくみてみると良いでしょう。こう言った単純ミスがどこにあるのかすぐわからないのであれば、`MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`の使用も検討された方が良いでしょう。このクラス名で検索すればわかりやすい記事がすぐに何件もヒットします。

Comment: ご丁寧にお答え頂きありがとうございます。かなり見直したのですが、初歩的なミスで大変申し訳ありませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Host192.****

ここは`Host=192.～`です。転記ミスかもしれませんが。